# How to get value outside function using python and kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, kivy, kivy-language

this is a simple python kivy app, only text label and slider. This code works fine.

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivymd.uix.slider import Slider
from kivy.properties  import NumericProperty
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel

class Screen1(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen1, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        layout = FloatLayout()

        self.hours_value = MDLabel(text = "0", halign = "center", pos_hint = {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.80}, theme_text_color = 'Error')
        self.hours_slider = Slider(min = 0, max = 24, pos_hint = {'center_x':.5}, size_hint_x = .7)
        self.hours_slider.bind(value = self.on_value_hours)

        layout.add_widget(self.hours_value)
        layout.add_widget(self.hours_slider)
        self.add_widget(layout)

    def on_value_hours(self, instance, slider):
        self.hours_value.text = "%d"%slider
        print(instance)
        print("%d"%slider)
        return slider

class myapp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls = ThemeManager()
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Orange'
        self.theme_cls.accent_pallete = 'Blue'
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'

        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Screen1(name = 's1'))
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myapp().run()
```

But now I want to get value on slider outside my function `def on_value_hours(self, instance, slider):`

so I add this code `my_value_slider = on_value_hours()`

but I get a error **on_value_hours() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'self', 'instance', and 'slider'**

I tried to add `my_value_slider = on_value_hours(1,1,1)`

but this is also not working for me :(

give me a error **AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'hours_value'**

this is a full code but still give me a error. I want to get value outside on my function. Please help me.

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivymd.uix.slider import Slider
from kivy.properties  import NumericProperty
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel

class Screen1(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen1, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        layout = FloatLayout()

        self.hours_value = MDLabel(text = "0", halign = "center", pos_hint = {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.80}, theme_text_color = 'Error')
        self.hours_slider = Slider(min = 0, max = 24, pos_hint = {'center_x':.5}, size_hint_x = .7)
        self.hours_slider.bind(value = self.on_value_hours)

        layout.add_widget(self.hours_value)
        layout.add_widget(self.hours_slider)
        self.add_widget(layout)

    def on_value_hours(self, instance, slider):
        self.hours_value.text = "%d"%slider
        print(instance)
        print("%d"%slider)
        return slider

    my_value_slider = on_value_hours(1,1,1)

class myapp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls = ThemeManager()
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Orange'
        self.theme_cls.accent_pallete = 'Blue'
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'

        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Screen1(name = 's1'))
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myapp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
class Screen1(Screen):
    # slider value
    my_value_slider = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen1, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        layout = FloatLayout()

        self.hours_value = MDLabel(text = "0", halign = "center", pos_hint = {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.80}, theme_text_color = 'Error')
        self.hours_slider = Slider(min = 0, max = 24, pos_hint = {'center_x':.5}, size_hint_x = .7)
        self.hours_slider.bind(value = self.on_value_hours)

        layout.add_widget(self.hours_value)
        layout.add_widget(self.hours_slider)
        self.add_widget(layout)

    def on_value_hours(self, instance, slider):
        self.hours_value.text = "%d"%slider
        print(instance)
        print("%d"%slider)

        # save value
        self.my_value_slider = slider
        return slider
```

Comment: thank you so much! this is working for me :) you're the god

Comment: this is fine but only works one this class, how to make this a acces for another class?

Comment: You do that through a reference to `Screen1`, which can be obtained from your `ScreenManager`.

Comment: If I type for another class 
`s = Screen1()`
`the_value = s.my_value_slider`
`print(the_value)`
this give me a 0 value

Comment: Yes, because that is not the correct way to access the variable. The code `s = Screen1()` creates a new instance of `Screen1`, and does not reference the instance that is in your GUI. You should be able to do something like `App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('s1').my_value_slider`.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is more like your initial code, where `my_slider_value` would be a class variable (as opposed to an instance variable):

```
class Screen1(Screen):
    # class variable
    my_value_slider = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen1, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        layout = FloatLayout()

        self.hours_value = MDLabel(text = "0", halign = "center", pos_hint = {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.80}, theme_text_color = 'Error')
        self.hours_slider = Slider(min = 0, max = 24, pos_hint = {'center_x':.5}, size_hint_x = .7)
        self.hours_slider.bind(value = self.on_value_hours)

        layout.add_widget(self.hours_value)
        layout.add_widget(self.hours_slider)
        self.add_widget(layout)

    def on_value_hours(self, instance, slider):
        self.hours_value.text = "%d"%slider
        print(instance)
        print("%d"%slider)

        # update value of class variable
        Screen1.my_value_slider = slider

        return slider
```

You can then access `my_value_slider` as `Screen1.my_value_slider`. Note that no parens are used in that access. The disadvantage of this approach is that `my_value_slider` is not a `Property`, so you can't bind to it.